# Are there any examples of this kind of PDE $\frac{\partial \rho(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F(\rho(t,x))}{\partial x}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I study a PDE writing as $\frac{\partial \rho(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F(\rho(t,x))}{\partial x}$ for some specific function $F$.

Is there a theory or some well-known example of this family of PDE ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're actually asking about, but for example the inviscid Burgers equation $u_t = \partial_x ( \frac12 u^2)$ is of that form. If you're looking for theory, try searching for “hyperbolic conservation laws”.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial \rho(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial F(\rho(t,x))}{\partial x} \tag 1$$
I suppose that the function $F$ is known (given), say : $F(X)$.

Thus the derivative wrt $X$ is a known function as well, say : $G(X)=F'(X)=\frac{dF}{dX}$ .
$$\frac{\partial F(\rho)}{\partial x}=G(\rho)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$
The PDE $(1)$ equivalently is :

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=G(\rho)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$
$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}-G(\rho)\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}=0 \tag 2$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-G(\rho)}=\frac{d\rho}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $d\rho=0$ :
$$\rho=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving  $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-G(c_1)}$
$$x+G(c_1)\:t=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_1=\Phi(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{\rho=\Phi\big(x+G(\rho)\:t\big)} \tag 3$$
$\Phi$ is an arbitrary function.

If some boundary condition is specified, one have to determine the function $\Phi$. Then putting it into Eq.$(3)$ gives the particular solution (on implicit form) which satisfies both the PDE an the condition.

Depending on the given function $F$ thus depending on the given function $G$ , the implicit equation can or can't be reduced on the explicit form $\rho(x,t)$ .

EXAMPLE :

With given function $F(X)=X^2 \quad\implies\quad G(X)=2X$
$$\rho=\Phi\big(x+2\rho\:t\big)$$
$\Phi$ is arbitrary until a condition be specified.

For example with initial condition $\rho(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$

$\rho(x,0)=\sqrt{x}=\Phi\big(x+0\big)$

Now the function $\Phi$ is known : $\Phi(x)=\sqrt{x}$ . We put it into the above general solution where the argument is not $x$ but is $(x+2\rho\:t)$

$$\rho=\sqrt{x+2\rho\:t}$$
$$\rho^2-2\rho\:t-x=0$$
$$\rho(x,t)=t+\sqrt{t^2+x}$$